# Por qué el código sigue adelante aunque no se cumpla la condición

Tags: javascript, html5

Básicamente tengo un código para que el usuario elija el método de ordenamiento que desea usar el código funciona me toma y ordena los números con el método selecciona en el select del html, pero el error que note es que cuando la primera condición no se cumple me toma la condición 2 y me la hace pasar como la uno es decir que si yo borro el algoritmo quicksort y lo selecciono en el selecta me utiliza el shellsort para ordenarme los números y lo que deseo es que si la opción elegida no tiene en este caso el algoritmo para ordenar me salga un alert o algo que me diga error,deseo que si la condición no se cumple  el código no se siga ejecutando

```js
function Ordenar(){
var datos= procesar();

function procesar(){//Funcion para obtener el valor de la opcion
    var seleccion= document.getElementById("List");
    var indice= seleccion.options.selectedIndex;
    var opcion=seleccion.options[indice].value;
    var metodo = document.getElementById("SinOrden").value.split(",").map(Number);
    console.log("Usastes el Metodo:"+" "+opcion)
      
    //Condiciones del option 
    if  (opcion="0"){var ordenados = quickSort(metodo)}; 
    if  (opcion="1"){var ordenados = shellSort(metodo)};
    if  (opcion="2"){var ordenados = insertionSort(metodo)};
    if  (opcion="3"){var ordenados = selectionSort(metodo)};
    if  (opcion="4"){var ordenados = burbuja(metodo)};
    if  (opcion="5"){var ordenados = mergeSort(metodo)};
    document.getElementById("ConOrder").value = ordenados;};
    
}

//---------------------------Metodo de ordenamientoQuickSort-----------------------------------
 function quickSort( [ x = [], ...xs ] ){
   return ( x.length === 0 ) ? [] : 
    [...quickSort( xs.filter( y => y <= x ) ),x,...quickSort( xs.filter( y => y > x ) )];}n
//---------------------------Metodo de ordenamiento quicksort-----------------------------------
   console.time('ShellSort');
   function shellSort(array){
   var brechas = [701, 301, 132, 57, 23, 10, 4, 1];
   for ( var g = 0; g < brechas.length; ++g ){
   for ( var i = brechas[ g ]; i < array.length; ++i ){
         var temp = array[ i ];
         var j = i;
   for ( ; j >= brechas[ g ] && array[j-brechas[ g ] ] > temp;
         j -= brechas[ g ] ){
         array[ j ] = array[ j - brechas[ g ] ];
      }
      array[ j ] = temp;
    }
  }

  return array;
}
  var a = new Array(15000);
  for (var n = 0; n < a.length; n++){
    a[n] = n * n;
}
  console.timeEnd('ShellSort'); 
 //--------------------------------------Metodo de ordenamiento insert---------------------------
 console.time('InsertSort');
 function insertionSort(array){
  var l = array.length;
  var j, temporal;

  for ( var i = 1; i < l; i++ ){
    j = i;
    temporal = array[ i ];
    while ( j > 0 && array[ j - 1 ] > temporal ){
      array[ j ] = array[ j - 1 ];
      j--;
    }
    array[ j ] = temporal;
  }

  return array;
};
var a = new Array(15000);
for (var n = 0; n < a.length; n++) {
    a[n] = n * n;
}
console.timeEnd('InsertSort'); 
//------------------------------------------SelectionSort---------------------------------------
console.time('selectionSort');
function selectionSort(array){
  for ( var j = 0; j < array.length; ++j ){
        var i = iMin = j;
  for ( ++i; i < array.length; ++i ){
      ( array[ i ] < array[ iMin ] ) && ( iMin = i );
    }
    [ array[ j ], array[ iMin ] ] = [ array[ iMin ], array[ j ] ];
  }
  return array;
}
  var a = new Array(15000);
  for (var n = 0; n < a.length; n++) {
    a[n] = n * n;
}
 
var a = new Array(15000);
for (var n = 0; n < a.length; n++) {
    a[n] = n * n;
}
console.timeEnd('selectionSort'); 
//-----------------------Metodo de Ordenamiento Bublesort------------------------------------------
console.time('BurbleSort');
function burbuja(arreglo)
{

    for(i=0;i<(arreglo.length-1);i++)
    for(j=0;j<(arreglo.length-i);j++){
    
     if(arreglo[j]>arreglo[j+1]){
             aux=arreglo[j];
             arreglo[j]=arreglo[j+1];
             arreglo[j+1]=aux;
 
        }
    }
     return arreglo
}

var a = new Array(15000);
for (var n = 0; n < a.length; n++) {
    a[n] = n * n;
}
console.timeEnd('BurbleSort'); 

//--------------------------Metodo de ordenamiento Mergesort----------------------------------
 console.time('MergeSort');
 function mergeSort (array){
     
 if (array.length === 1){return array;}

  var longitud = Math.floor(array.length / 2) //obtiene e lelemento central de la matriz redondeado hacia abajo
  var derecha = array.slice(0, longitud) // elementos en el lado izquierdo
  var izquierda = array.slice(longitud)  // elementos en el lado derecho
        
  return merge(mergeSort(izquierda), mergeSort(derecha));
}
      
 function merge  (izquierda, derecha){
  var result = [];
  var il = ir = 0;
    while (il < izquierda.length && ir < derecha.length){
       if (izquierda[il] < derecha[ir]){result.push(izquierda[il]) 
       il++} 
       else{result.push(derecha[ir])
       ir++}
  }
    return [...result,...izquierda.slice(il),...derecha.slice(ir)];
}

var a = new Array(15000);
for (var n = 0; n < a.length; n++) {
    a[n] = n * n;
}
 
console.timeEnd('MergeSort'); 

console.time('quickSort'); 
var a = new Array(15000);
for (var n = 0; n < a.length; n++){a[n] = n * n;}
console.timeEnd('quickSort');
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
 <title>Proyecto final del primer semestre</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilos.css">
 <script src="js.js"></script>
</head>
 <body>
 <header>Usa Diferentes Metodos Para Ordenar Tus Numeros</header><!-- /header -->
  
  <select    id="List" class="select">
    <option  value="">Elige una Opcion</option>
    <option  value="0"     id="quickSort">Ordena con QuickSort</option>
    <option  value="1" id="Insert" >Ordena con InsertSort</option>
    <option  value="2"     id="ShellSort">Ordena con ShellSort</option>
    <option  value="3" id="selectionSort">Ordena con SelectionSort</option>
    <option  value="4"       id="burbuja">Ordena con BurbleSort</option>
    <option  value="5"     id="mergeSort">Ordena con MergeSort</option>
  </select>

 <textarea class="intro box " type="text" name="Desordenado"placeholder="Introduce un grupo de numeros de forma desordenada" id="SinOrden"></textarea>
 
<div class="poder">
 <button class="ingresar" type="submit" value="Ordenar" onclick="Ordenar()">Ordenar</button>
 <button class="letras"   type="reset" value="Limpiar" onclick="location.reload()">Limpiar</button>
</div>

<textarea class="out" id="ConOrder" type="text" class="box2" placeholder="Numeros Ordenados"></textarea>


  
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es debido a la sintaxis del if. Esta es incorrecta. Al tener un solo simbolo de = estas asigando un nuevo valor a tu variable opcion. Lo recomentable es hacerlo con === [para que valide el valor y tipo.](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp)

```
var ordenados = new Array[];
if  (opcion==="0"){ordenados = quickSort(metodo)};
```

Ahora. Con esto resuelves. Pero para ese caso te recomiendo cambiar la serie de if por [switch](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/switch) para no leer todas las opciones al validar, que lea una vez el valor.

```
var ordenados = new Array[];
switch (opcion) {
  case "0":
    ordenados = quickSort(metodo)
    break;
  case "1":
    ordenados = shellSort(metodo)
    [break;]
  ...
  default: break;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Saludos puedes intentar realizar algo como esto:

```js
function Ordenar(){
var datos= procesar();
function procesar(){//Funcion para obtener el valor de la opcion
    var seleccion= document.getElementById("List");
    var indice= seleccion.options.selectedIndex;
    var opcion=seleccion.options[indice].value;
    var metodo = document.getElementById("SinOrden").value.split(",").map(Number);
    //console.log("Usastes el Metodo:"+" "+opcion)
      
    //Condiciones del option 
    if  (opcion="0"){
     if ((typeof window["quickSort"] !== 'undefined') && ((typeof window["quickSort"] === 'function'))){ 
       var ordenados = quickSort(metodo)
     }else { 
       alert('El metodo no existe');
        return false;
     }
    }//end option 0
    if  (opcion="1"){var ordenados = shellSort(metodo)};
    if  (opcion="2"){var ordenados = insertionSort(metodo)};
    if  (opcion="3"){var ordenados = selectionSort(metodo)};
    if  (opcion="4"){var ordenados = burbuja(metodo)};
    if  (opcion="5"){var ordenados = mergeSort(metodo)};
    document.getElementById("ConOrder").value = ordenados;};
    
}
//---------------------------Metodo de ordenamientoQuickSort-----------------------------------
 /*function quickSort( [ x = [], ...xs ] ){
   return ( x.length === 0 ) ? [] : 
    [...quickSort( xs.filter( y => y <= x ) ),x,...quickSort( xs.filter( y => y > x ) )];}n
    */
//---------------------------Metodo de ordenamiento quicksort-----------------------------------
   //console.time('ShellSort');
   function shellSort(array){
   var brechas = [701, 301, 132, 57, 23, 10, 4, 1];
   for ( var g = 0; g < brechas.length; ++g ){
   for ( var i = brechas[ g ]; i < array.length; ++i ){
         var temp = array[ i ];
         var j = i;
   for ( ; j >= brechas[ g ] && array[j-brechas[ g ] ] > temp;
         j -= brechas[ g ] ){
         array[ j ] = array[ j - brechas[ g ] ];
      }
      array[ j ] = temp;
    }
  }

  return array;
}
  var a = new Array(15000);
  for (var n = 0; n < a.length; n++){
    a[n] = n * n;
}
  //console.timeEnd('ShellSort'); 
 //--------------------------------------Metodo de ordenamiento insert---------------------------
 //console.time('InsertSort');
 function insertionSort(array){
  var l = array.length;
  var j, temporal;

  for ( var i = 1; i < l; i++ ){
    j = i;
    temporal = array[ i ];
    while ( j > 0 && array[ j - 1 ] > temporal ){
      array[ j ] = array[ j - 1 ];
      j--;
    }
    array[ j ] = temporal;
  }

  return array;
};
var a = new Array(15000);
for (var n = 0; n < a.length; n++) {
    a[n] = n * n;
}
//console.timeEnd('InsertSort'); 
//------------------------------------------SelectionSort---------------------------------------
//console.time('selectionSort');
function selectionSort(array){
  for ( var j = 0; j < array.length; ++j ){
        var i = iMin = j;
  for ( ++i; i < array.length; ++i ){
      ( array[ i ] < array[ iMin ] ) && ( iMin = i );
    }
    [ array[ j ], array[ iMin ] ] = [ array[ iMin ], array[ j ] ];
  }
  return array;
}
  var a = new Array(15000);
  for (var n = 0; n < a.length; n++) {
    a[n] = n * n;
}
 
var a = new Array(15000);
for (var n = 0; n < a.length; n++) {
    a[n] = n * n;
}
//console.timeEnd('selectionSort'); 
//-----------------------Metodo de Ordenamiento Bublesort------------------------------------------
//console.time('BurbleSort');
function burbuja(arreglo)
{

    for(i=0;i<(arreglo.length-1);i++)
    for(j=0;j<(arreglo.length-i);j++){
    
     if(arreglo[j]>arreglo[j+1]){
             aux=arreglo[j];
             arreglo[j]=arreglo[j+1];
             arreglo[j+1]=aux;
 
        }
    }
     return arreglo
}

var a = new Array(15000);
for (var n = 0; n < a.length; n++) {
    a[n] = n * n;
}
//console.timeEnd('BurbleSort'); 

//--------------------------Metodo de ordenamiento Mergesort----------------------------------
 //console.time('MergeSort');
 function mergeSort (array){
     
 if (array.length === 1){return array;}

  var longitud = Math.floor(array.length / 2) //obtiene e lelemento central de la matriz redondeado hacia abajo
  var derecha = array.slice(0, longitud) // elementos en el lado izquierdo
  var izquierda = array.slice(longitud)  // elementos en el lado derecho
        
  return merge(mergeSort(izquierda), mergeSort(derecha));
}
      
 function merge  (izquierda, derecha){
  var result = [];
  var il = ir = 0;
    while (il < izquierda.length && ir < derecha.length){
       if (izquierda[il] < derecha[ir]){result.push(izquierda[il]) 
       il++} 
       else{result.push(derecha[ir])
       ir++}
  }
    return [...result,...izquierda.slice(il),...derecha.slice(ir)];
}

var a = new Array(15000);
for (var n = 0; n < a.length; n++) {
    a[n] = n * n;
}
 
//console.timeEnd('MergeSort'); 

//console.time('quickSort'); 
var a = new Array(15000);
for (var n = 0; n < a.length; n++){a[n] = n * n;}
//console.timeEnd('quickSort');
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
 <title>Proyecto final del primer semestre</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilos.css">
 <script src="js.js"></script>
</head>
 <body>
 <header>Usa Diferentes Metodos Para Ordenar Tus Numeros</header><!-- /header -->
  <label for="">Ingrese los numeros: </label><br>
 <textarea class="intro box " type="text" name="Desordenado"placeholder="Introduce un grupo de numeros de forma desordenada" id="SinOrden"></textarea>
<br>
  <select    id="List" class="select">
    <option  value="">Elige una Opcion</option>
    <option  value="0"     id="quickSort">Ordena con QuickSort</option>
    <option  value="1" id="Insert" >Ordena con InsertSort</option>
    <option  value="2"     id="ShellSort">Ordena con ShellSort</option>
    <option  value="3" id="selectionSort">Ordena con SelectionSort</option>
    <option  value="4"       id="burbuja">Ordena con BurbleSort</option>
    <option  value="5"     id="mergeSort">Ordena con MergeSort</option>
  </select>

<div class="poder">
 <button class="ingresar" type="submit" value="Ordenar" onclick="Ordenar()">Ordenar</button>
 <button class="letras"   type="reset" value="Limpiar" onclick="location.reload()">Limpiar</button>
</div>

<textarea class="out" id="ConOrder" type="text" class="box2" placeholder="Numeros Ordenados"></textarea>


  
</body>
</html>
```

Si te fijas dentro de tu **opcion 0**  he agregado una validación para saber si la funcion invocada existe en este caso "**quickSort**" si existe realizo el metodo de ordenamiento caso contrario muestro un alert y coloco un "**return false**" esto me permite que no continue hacia otra opción o función, asi puedes realizar la validacion de cada una de las opciones.

Espero te sirva y suerte.!!